# 回答にあるソースコードを別の場所で使っても構いませんか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

スタック・オーバーフローへの投稿に書かれているソースコードをコピーして、自分のプログラムの一部として利用したり、他のサイトへ投稿したりしても構いませんか？

これらのソースコードは、何らかの著作権・ライセンスで保護されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**何の著作権表示もなくコピー＆ペーストすることは通常できません。**

スタック・オーバーフロー上の多くのコンテンツは [Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) でライセンスされています。より詳しくは、ページ下部にリンクされている[利用規約](https://stackexchange.com/legal)をご覧ください。

このライセンスがかかっているソースコードを使う場合、[Stack Overflow Blog の記事](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)によると、以下のことをする必要があります。

> 1. **そのコンテンツが元々スタック・オーバーフローや Stack Exchange ネットワーク上のものであるということを明示する。** 大々的に書けということではなく、ほんの1行短く書いてあればOKです。
> 2. そのコンテンツが載っていた **元々の質問を直接紐付ける。** （例: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. それぞれの質問と回答の **著者名を書く。**
> 4. それぞれの著者名は、 **その人のプロフィールページを直接紐付ける。** (例: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> ただしここで言う「直接紐付ける」ためには、たとえば Web ページ上だと、標準的な HTML を使ってハイパーリンクをつけ、Javascript が無効化されていてもリンクされているようにする必要があります。また、リンク先として短縮アドレスやリダイレクションを使わないでください。更には、そのリンクを [nofollow](https://googleblog.blogspot.jp/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html) にしないでください。
>
> <sup>([Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jeffatwood/) による[こちらの投稿](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)を元にしました。)</sup>

ただし、著作者によってその投稿が[パブリック・ドメイン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)になっていたり、そのコンテンツ自体どこかからペーストしてきていてライセンス違反してしまっていたりする場合は、この限りではありません。そもそも後者はスタック・オーバーフローの利用規約違反ですが、残念ながらそのような投稿はしばしば見受けられます。ですから、 **充分に注意してください。**

---

#### 補記

2016年1月頃、Stack Exchange ネットワーク上に投稿されたソースコードのライセンスを MIT License にしようという動きがありましたが、結局行われませんでした ([参考1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/341401)、[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/341401))。今後もこのような議論が起こるかもしれないため、厳密なライセンスを知るには[利用規約](https://stackexchange.com/legal)をよくご確認ください。

#### 参考リンク

- ["Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527/341401) -- Stack Exchange Meta
- ["Can we get some explicit clarification on the *intended* legal usage of code from SO answers?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286582/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

Comment: 上記は他のサイトへコピペする際の指針だと思います(「リンク」という表現からそう読み取りました)。
自分のコードへコピペする場合の指針もあった方が良いのではないでしょうか?
確かに英語版を読んでも書いてなかったのですが、「FAQ」としてはあった方が良いと思います。

Comment: @masm ご指摘ありがとうございます。少し書き換えました。一応コミュニティwiki投稿にしておりますので、細かく気になる点がございましたら書きなおして頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 日本の法律だとそもそも短いコードスニペットに著作権が発生するのかどうかという問題があるのですが、実際どうなんですかね……。