# 回答にあるソースコードを商用利用しても構いませんか？

Tags: サポート, ライセンス

ソースコードの利用について、過去の質問を参照したところ、以下のように記載されていました。
[回答にあるソースコードを別の場所で使っても構いませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2529)

> スタック・オーバーフロー上の多くのコンテンツは Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike でライセンスされています。より詳しくは、ページ下部にリンクされている利用規約をご覧ください。

回答に適用されるライセンスは「CC BY-SA 4.0」のため、商用利用が可能です。

一方、利用規約の「6. Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing」には
以下の記載があります。

> Any other downloading, copying, or storing of any public Network Content (other than Subscriber Content or content made available via the Stack Overflow API) for other than personal, noncommercial use is expressly prohibited without prior written permission from Stack Overflow or from the copyright holder identified in the copyright notice per the Creative Commons License.

これは、商用利用を禁止しているように読めます。

2つの記載が矛盾しているように思いますが、回答にあるソースコードの商用利用は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

商用利用して構いません。

利用規約「6.」の記述は「Stack Overflow Content」と「Subscriber Content」に分かれています。

- 「Stack Overflow Content」:
  「Subscriber Content」を除くサイト上のコンテンツ。スタック・オーバーフローおよび/または第三者の著作物。ロゴや利用規約など？
- 「Subscriber Content」:
  この利用規約に同意したユーザーの著作物。質問・回答など。

質問で引用されている記述は、「Stack Overflow Content」に関する部分です。

> other than Subscriber Content

とある通り、この部分の記述は「Subscriber Content」に関して適用されません。ユーザーが提供するコンテンツは「Subscriber Content」に分類され、それは CC BY-SA 4.0 で提供するものと後段で定められています。

なお、そもそもコードの断片に著作権が発生するか否かは議論の分かれる所だと思います。

Answer (score 4):

ライセンスとしてはmjyさんの回答の通りかとおもいますが、「Subscriber Content」がCC BY-SA 4.0で提供されるためには前提としてその投稿が真に投稿者の権利下にあることが必要です。

具体的には他サイトの内容を転載した投稿については投稿者が「stack overflowがコンテンツをCCで提供することを許諾する」権利を有しないので、stack overflowの規約は意味をなしません。

Wikipediaなんかはわりとこの点厳しくやっているので「掲載内容は権利的に問題がない」という前提でもリスクは低いですが、このサイトがどうかというと残念ながらライセンス的に健全な状態を保とうという点にはほぼ無頓着なので、利用したい側が個別に問題ないことを確認する必要があります。

商利用前提なら現実的には「やめておきましょう」ですね

---

余談:
第三者の著作物を適法に「引用」して構成されたコンテンツであっても、引用部分を単独(または適法な引用として成立しない方法分量)で抜き出して流用する場合は元の著作者の権利が優先しますので、(引用部分がもともとCCでないかぎり)CCで利用することはできません。